# How to access custom attributes from the current product in JavaScript?

Tags: magento2, javascript, custom-attributes, requirejs

I added the following in `view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_Name::js/my_script.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

And in `view/frontend/web/js/my_script.js`:

```
require([
    // ???
], function (
    // ...
) {
    // ...
});
```

Here I thought it would suffice to require something like `'Magento_Catalog/catalog/product'` to get the product, but it doesn’t work.

If I require `'Magento_Catalog/catalog/product'` I get an `Uncaught Error: Script error` because it doesn’t exist. `Magento_Catalog/js/product/view/product-info` gives me an `Observable` object I don’t know how to use. `Magento_Catalog/js/product/view/product-info-resolver` gives me a callback that I can use to get the product id.

What should I `require` to get the current product’s informations? I’m trying to determine if the product has a boolean custom attribute set to `true`.

I’m using Magento 2.4.x.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the value of php variables to a javascript file using requirejs-config.js

Create the files as shown below.

> **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description"
                name="product.custom.attr" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_attributes.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
      '*': {
        'customattr': 'Magento_Catalog/js/customattr'
      }
    },
    shim: {
      'customattr': ['jquery']
    }
};
```

> **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/custom_attributes.phtml**

```
<?php

$product = $block->getProduct();
$productId = $product->getId();
$sku = $product->getSku();

?>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*":{
            "customattr": {
                "id": "<?= $productId; ?>",
                "sku": "<?= $sku; ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

> **app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/web/js/customattr.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    $.widget('custom.attr', {

        _create: function() {
            var id = this.options.id;
            var sku = this.options.sku;
            console.log(id);
            console.log(sku);
        }

    });

    return $.custom.attr;
});
```

Run following commands to render the changes of new files

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: Thank you! ____